# python Concurrent Futures gives different results each time

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I am very confused why the concurrent.futures module is giving me different results each time. I have a function, say foo(), which runs on segments of a larger set of data d.

I consistently break this larger data set d into parts and make a list
`d_parts = [d1, d2, d3, ...]`

Then following the documentation, I do the following

```
results = [executor.submit(foo, d) for d in d_parts]
```

which is supposed to give me a list of "futures" objects in the order of `foo(d1), foo(d2)`, and so on.

However, when I try to compile results with

```
done, _ = concurrent.futures.wait(results)
```

The list of results stored in `done` seem to be out of order, i.e. they are not the returns of `foo(d1), foo(d2)` but some different ordering. Hence, running this program on the same data set multiple times yields different results, as a result of the indeterminacy of which finishes first (the `d1, d2`... are roughly same size) Is there a reason why, since it seems that `wait()` should preserve the ordering in which the jobs were submitted?
Thanks!

Comment: if the order is important, perhaps you could enumerate d_parts and pass the index to foo that would also echo it back when returning

Comment: so you are saying, to enumerate in the results = [executuor.submit..] part, pass the index into foo and manually reorder afterwards? Just to confirm. (That actually sounds like a great idea. Thanks!)

Comment: yes, that is just my first instinct though.

Comment: Thanks Jon, wondering if you know whether the shuffling of orders is known in concurrent.futures.wait()? I know that futures are returned as they complete (and hence order may be shuffled) using concurrent.futures.as_completed(), but didn't expect this for the wait method...

Comment: I think the order is just the order that each completed rather than the order they were submitted. I'm guess the same plumbing  is used for `wait()` and `as_completed()` but that is pure speculation on my part.

Comment: I am trying to some tests to see what is happening with the ordering, for those two methods. Will update this post accordingly. Thanks for everything.